# JavaFX: Problems to use setOnCloseRequest within a Controller

Tags: javafx-2

I want to use setOnCloseRequest after my stage has been started but i get almost a NullPointerException although i set the right controller.

I click on a menuitem to open the stage and after the menu is open i want to use the close button. I think the method tries to access until the controller has been initialized.Actually i want to say: Please controller you are just allowed to do something after you are initialized.

[image]

THis is my code of the controller.

```
 if (KundenDatenController.getInstance() != null) {

        ((Stage) (KundenDatenController.getInstance().kundenControllerPane.
                getScene().getWindow())).setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(WindowEvent t) {
                t.consume();
                if (generalControler.controlEmptyTextField(pflichtfelder)) {
                    ((Stage) (kundenControllerPane.getScene().getWindow())).close();

                } else if (!generalControler.controlEmptyTextField(pflichtfelder)) {
                    FXOptionPane.showConfirmDialog((Stage) (kundenControllerPane.getScene().getWindow()),
                            "Sollen die Eingaben wirklich verworfen werden?",
                            "Programm schliessen");
                    if (status.equals("Laden")) {
                        KundenUebersichtController.getInstance().setStatus("Aufnehmen");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Could you provide the stack trace ?

Comment: yes, you can see it here:

http://pastebin.com/bsFz9EAp

Comment: The line number does not match. What is the `null` pointer ? Is it `generalControler`?

Comment: Im not sure if i understand your question right, but the null pointer is the kundenController. You can scroll also to the right on pastebin.

Comment: the kundenControllerPane or the generalController ?

Comment: It is complicated to help you, because you are providing only a portion of your code. I don't see where kundenControllerPane is declared. You should provide an [sscce](sscce.org).